# Fill table (PK column A, PK column B) with table of elements B, where column A does not have B - list pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, to me comes **Table2** (**PK Text**) filled with elements **FIRST**, **SECOND**, **THIRD**, **FORTH**.
I need to insert this element to **TABLE1** where these elements are missing.

**TABLE1**

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  Text  |
+----+--------+
| A  | FIRST  |
| A  | SECOND |
| A  | THIRD  |
| B  | FIRST  |
| B  | THIRD  |
| C  | FIRST  |
+----+--------+
```

> So **ID A** misses FORTH

```
| A  | FORTH |
```

> Should be inserted
>
> **B** misses **SECOND** and **FORTH** and so on
>
> Answer should be something like that
>
> ```
> +----+--------+
> | ID |  Text  |
> +----+--------+
> | A  | FIRST  |
> | A  | SECOND |
> | A  | THIRD  |
> | A  | FORTH  |
> | B  | FIRST  |
> | B  | SECOND |
> | B  | THIRD  |
> | B  | FORTH  |
> | C  | FIRST  |
> | C  | SECOND |
> | C  | THIRD  |
> | C  | FORTH  |
> +----+--------+
> ```

Comment: You've said what you want, but what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cross join` the `text`s from `table2` with the distinct `id`s availabel in `table1` and filter on the missing tuples with a `not exists` condition, like so:

```
insert into table1(id, text)
select t1.id, t2.text
from table2 t2
cross join (select distinct id from table1) t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table1 t11
    where t11.id = t1.id and t11.text = t2.text
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross join the distinct `ID`s with the distinct `Text`s and left join the table to get the unmatched rows of the table:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, Text)
SELECT i.ID, d.Text
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE1) i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Text FROM TABLE1) d
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t ON t.ID = i.ID AND t.Text = d.Text
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=686687abb9a2e5d08872c4d3b8233966).
If there is a case that any of the values 'FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD' or 'FOURTH' is missing from the table then use this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, Text)
SELECT i.ID, d.Text
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE1) i
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 'FIRST' Text UNION ALL SELECT 'SECOND'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'THIRD' UNION ALL SELECT 'FOURTH'
) d
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t ON t.ID = i.ID AND t.Text = d.Text
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85dbf827f1c3b549af285cb76ff09f4c).